# sharing objects in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

This is a noob question. If I have a ViewController and inside that class I have an object called UserInfo and other ViewController, lets just call it X,Y,Z, etc..etc.

What do I need to do so that those X,Y,Z can use the information of UserInfo?

Well I can have another info called UserInfo inside X,Y,Z and pass UserInfo inside, but I don't think this is good OOP technique. I think inheritance is needed here... but I don't think that it is right too, as the only commonality they have is only the UserInfo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View controllers are just objects, you have to remember that.

If you're in your first view controller and it has a property `NSString *aString` to pass it to the next view controller you just make the second view controller's `NSString *aString` property equal to the first one.

Basically do this:

```
MyNextViewController *viewControllerTwo = [[MyNextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[viewControllerTwo setAString:self.aString];
```

if you subclass all you inherit are the properties, and not their values.

Comment: that's what I actually meant... so in your case, I need an aString for all of the subclass

Comment: you just need a variable of the same type in both view controllers. To pass between them you just do `object.variable = newObject.variable;` or as above.